# Setting hyperref reference with xstring

Tags: hyperref, xstring

I am trying to generate `hyperref` links programmatically, using `xstring`. For example, in the code below I would like `\hyperref[reference\FirstNumber{1,2}]{first line}` to be equivalent to `\hyperref[reference1]{first line}`. I'm confused because I can put `1` in a macro, and the proper result obtains. When I put my `xstring` macro in place of that, it fails. I have a vague sense that this has to do with when the macros are expanded, but I can't get farther than that.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,xstring}
\begin{document}
\def\FirstNumber#1{\IfSubStr{#1}{,}{\StrBefore{#1}{,}}{#1}}

The first number is \FirstNumber{1}.\label{reference1}

The first number is \FirstNumber{2,3}.\label{reference2}

\def\NumberOne{1}

\hyperref[reference\NumberOne]{first line}

\hyperref[reference\FirstNumber{1,2}]{first line} % error occurs here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label name must expand to a string, but `\FirstNumber` is not expandable.
The `xstring` macros provide an optional argument at the end, that takes the result, which can then be used inside the label name.

```
\FirstNumber{1,2}[\MyFirstNumber]%
\hyperref[reference\MyFirstNumber]{first line} % error occurs here
```